# How do I calculate annualized return with NA in data?

Tags: r

I need to calculate the annualized return from a quarterly return data series. A sample data is created as below

```
df <- data.frame(v1 = c(0.01, 0.03, 0.02,0.05, 0.06,0.03,0.01, NA), V2 = c(NA, 0.1, 0.02,NA,0.03,0.05,0.11, 0.2))
```

My code is this:

```
df_annual <- rollapply(df, width = 4, Return.annualized, scale =4, align = "right", fill = NA)
```

The result I got is

```
v1        V2

NA         NA
NA         NA
NA         NA
0.114161    0.258884
0.169318    0.212756
0.169318    0.139818
0.157854    0.275849
0.139251    0.440558
```

I expect to get the following result:

```
V1         V2

NA          NA
NA          NA
NA          NA
0.114161    NA
0.169318    NA
0.169318    NA
0.157854    NA
NA          0.440558
```

In other words, I only want R to calculate annualized returns with at least four consecutive numbers. I also wonder how did I get the first result. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** `Return.annualized` omits NA values and then calculates the annualized return of what is left.  If you want an output of NA whenever any input is NA then check for an NA in the input and output NA if encountered; otherwise, run `Return.annualized`.

```
library(PerformanceAnalytics)
library(zoo)

Return.annualizedNA <- function(x, ...) if (anyNA(x)) NA else Return.annualized(x, ...)
rollapplyr(df, width = 4, Return.annualizedNA, scale = 4, fill = NA)
```

**2)** Another possibility is to just do it directly using `prod`

```
library(zoo)

rollapplyr(df + 1, 4, prod, fill = NA) - 1
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It's very helpful. On your second solution, what If I need two-year annualized return for the quarterly data?

Comment: Use 8 to get two years and take the appropriate sqrt to get the annual return.